# As a computational chemist, which online resources are available for Ph.D. level jobs?

Tags: phd, job-search, online-resource, chemistry

Which online resources are available for job search at the Ph.D. level in the computational chemistry field?

Comment: Do you mean in private industry or in an instructional capacity?  I suspect that these answers will vary wildly based on geographic region(s) your interested in, so it'd be nice to have that information.

Comment: Maybe you know if it but still : http://jobs.phds.org/physics-math

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best resources for jobs in computational chemistry (not limited to PhD level positions) is the job section of the [Computational Chemistry List](http://www.ccl.net/chemistry/a/jobs/index.shtml).

Another place where I've regularly seen relevant postings is the ["Computational Chemists" group on LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Computational-Chemists-94648).

Answer (score 1):

If you are based in Europe, or would consider a position in Europe, I strongly recommend the [CCP5 mailing-lists](http://www.ccp5.ac.uk/mailing.shtml) for this purpose. I also second the advice about the Computational Chemistry List, these are the two places I post job openings for my own group.

In the UK, all academic positions open are posted to [jobs.ac.uk](http://www.jobs.ac.uk), making it really invaluable for job search.

Finally, some journals have a job listings section as well, such as [Nature jobs](http://www.nature.com/naturejobs/science/), [Science Careers](http://sciencecareers.sciencemag.org). The learned society of your field might also have job listing, as e.g. the [Royal Society of Chemistry](http://jobs.rsc.org) or the ACS’s [Chemistry jobs](http://chemistryjobs.acs.org/jobs) listing.